# How did vowel a in L. maneō “to remain” come from PIE *mn-eh₁- “to remain” < PIE *men- “to stay, stand still”?

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european

AHD-IER (Watkins, 2011) P97 gives PIE *man-e- for L. maneō:

> Variant suffixed (stative) form
>   ***man-e-.**  MANOR, MANSE, MANSION, MENAGE; IMMANENT, PERMANENT, REMAIN, from Latin manere, to remain.

while EDLIL (Michiel de Vaan, 2008) P374:

> PIE *mn-eh₁- 'to remain'.
>
> at a stage preceding the Latin
>   **unrounding** of *mo- > *ma- in open syllables. In particular, initial m- could have played a **rounding role** in this process.

In P21, only find this one:

> 7.1 *o > a /b, l, m, w, kʷ_CV (Lat. badius, canem, lacus, lanius, manus, mare)

How can the vowel a in maneō reflect from PIE *men- "to stay, stand still"?

**PS**: this topic is related to this 2019 paper [Ablaut and the Latin Verb Aspects of Morphophonological Change](https://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/24098/1/Leppaenen_Ville.pdf), and the author has the same conclusion that none of the proposed PIE form can be safely accepted without problem.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The stem *man-* from PIE \*_m-n-_ seems straightforward; are you asking about the *-eō* part (how the Latin second conjugation came about)?

Comment: @Draconis Hi, I came accross this 2019 paper (https://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/24098/1/Leppaenen_Ville.pdf) where in p70, the author thinks this is not straightforward, as "I think that the current scholarship is not conclusive enough to show which ablaut grade Lat. manē- actually continues, and which changes it has undergone"

Comment: Ahh, so your question is something more like "which particular PIE form led to _maneō_", rather than "does _maneō_ actually come from *_m-n-_"? If you edit to make that clearer, I think it'll attract better attention.

Comment: Calvert **Watkins**, not Watkin.

Comment: @AlexB. Sorry for my bad memory, I have corrected it.

Comment: @Draconis You are right, the title of the post is ambiguous, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR: Nobody's sure, and none of the proposals are universally accepted.

It's pretty clear that *maneō* came from the PIE root **m-n-*, which has plenty of cognates across the IE world. But if I understand right, that's not what you're asking about.

The consonants come straight from PIE, and the *-e-* of the second conjugation is well-understood. The real mystery is the *-a-* in the middle. Most often, *-a-* comes from the laryngeal **h₂* (or **h₁* or **h₃* in Italic), but there's no sign of a laryngeal in this root.

The paper you've linked gives a number of different ways this might have developed, from big names like Sihler, De Vaan, and others. You've already read what they have to say on the matter; I'll add my own slightly more far-fetched theory.

> Latin *man-* may perhaps have come from the zero-grade stem, **mṇ-*. In Latin, this would have regularly developed into **men-* or **min-*, via (according to Meiser, in Klein's *Handbook*) some sort of intermediate **mẽ-*.
>
> But in the closely-related Sabellic languages, Meiser's **ẽ* instead becomes *an* in stressed (i.e. initial) syllables: compare Oscan *fanguam* "tongue (acc)" against Latin *linguam* (<**dẽgwām*), or Oscan *anter* "between" against Latin *inter* (<**ẽter*).
>
> So it's entirely possible that the Latin **men-* was affected, or possibly even replaced, by the Sabellic **man-*. This is attested with other words, such as *lupus* "wolf" (instead of the expected **lucus*), which shows the Sabellic shift of **kʷ* to *p* instead of the Latin **kʷ* → *k* / *u*_.

Unlikely? Perhaps—I can't find any actual attestation of a Sabellic verb **man-*, though the sound changes involved would be regular. But I've never seen a more regular explanation than this: they all require some sort of irregularity (in this case, the Sabellic influences). So I have to agree with Leppänen: "the current scholarship is not conclusive enough to show which ablaut grade Lat[in] *manē-* actually continues, and which changes it has undergone."

Comment: Thanks for your answering, I never heard this theory, and I do think it is possilble neighbouring languages affect latin, great point!